# Problem by Dictonary with Variable and Input

Tags: python

i am writting a code that is counting random Numbers. Everytime when i change the value in the script, everything is working. But when im changing the variable to inpu with Summe = input("YourNumber"), it is not working.

```
import random
import time

#MyNumber = input("YourNumber")
Summe = input("Suche deine Zahl")
for i in range(1, 101):
    RamdomNumber = random.randrange(1, 4)
    globals()[f"Number{i}"] = RamdomNumber

Dictonary = {k: v for k, v in globals().items() if not k.startswith("__")}

print({k: v for k, v in globals().items() if not k.startswith("__")})
 
print(sum(value == Summe for value in Dictonary.values()))
#Prozentsumme = Summe / 10
print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("Deine Nummer ist:", MyNumber)
#print("Deine Nummer gab es:", Summe , "Mal")
#print("Die Wahrscheinlichkeit liegt bei:", Prozentsumme * 100 , "Prozent")
```

Please somebody help me!!!!

Comment: shame on whoever told you that `globals()[f"Number{i}"]` was the way to implement a list!

Comment: Telling us "it is not working" doesn't really help.  Instead, tell us _what happens_, and explain how that is _different from what you wanted_.

Comment: I agree with @Samwise. Drop the use of `globals()` and use a list.

Comment: Did you mean to use `int(input(...))`?

Comment: `Summe` contains a string. All the `NumberX` variables contain integers. They won't be equal.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string will never equal an int -- if you're getting a number from `input()` and you want to compare it to an int value, convert it with `int()`.

You can also greatly simplify your dictionary code by just keeping the numbers in a regular old list.  There are very few instances where using `globals()` is a good idea, and this is not one of them!

```
import random

Summe = int(input("Suche deine Zahl"))

numbers = [random.randrange(1, 4) for _ in range(100)]
for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
    print(f"Number{i+1}: {n}")

print(sum(value == Summe for value in numbers))

print("Deine Nummer gab es:", Summe, "Mal")
```

Comment: Thanks bro, big help

Comment: Use `numbers.count(Summe)` instead of that unnecessary sum/generator expression.